# Using half-precision NumPy floats in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, cython

I'm trying to send float16 data to an Nvidia P100 card from some Cython code. When I was using float32, I could define my types in Cython like so:

```
DTYPE = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] mat = np.empty((100, 100), dtype=DTYPE)
```

But Cython can't find a defined type for np.float16_t, so I can't just replace the 32 with 16. If I try to provide another type that takes the same amount of space, like np.uint16_t, I get errors like:

```
Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('e')
```

When I google, all I can find is a thread from 2011 about people trying to figure out how to support it...surely there must be a solution by now?

Comment: It isn't completely obvious to me how numpy supports it given that GCC doesn't seem to on x86

Comment: (Possibly useful... https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/doc/source/reference/c-api.coremath.rst#half-precision-functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is "sort of, but it's a reasonable amount of work if you want to do any real calculations".

The basic problem is that C doesn't support a 16-bit float type on most PCs (because the processor instructions don't exist). Therefore, [what numpy has done](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.coremath.html#half-precision-functions) is `typedef`ed a 16-bit unsigned int to store the 16-bit float, and then written a set of functions to convert that to/from the supported float types. Any calculations using `np.float16` are actually done on 32-bit or 64-bit floats but the data is stored in the 16-bit format between calculations.

The consequence of this is that Cython doesn't have an easy way of generating valid C code for any calculations it needs to do. The consequence is that you may need to write out this C code yourself.

There are a number of levels of complexity, depending on what you actually want to do:

### 1) Don't type anything

Cython doesn't actually need you to specify any types - it compiles Python code happy. Therefore, don't assign types to the half-float arrays and just let them by Python objects. This may not be terribly fast but it's worth remembering that it will work.

### 2) To move data you can `view` it as `uint16`

If you're just shuffling data around then can define `uint16` arrays and use those to copy it from one place to another. Use the numpy `view` function to get the data in a format that Cython recognises and to get it back. However, you can't do maths in this mode (the answers will be meaningless).

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint16_t

import numpy as np

def just_move_stuff(x):
    assert x.dtype == np.float16
    # I've used memoryviews by cdef np.ndarray should be fine too
    cdef uint16_t[:] x_as_uint = x.view(np.uint16)

    cdef uint16_t[:] y_as_uint = np.empty(x.shape,dtype=np.uint16)

    for n in range(x_as_uint.shape[0]):
        y_as_uint[n] = x_as_uint[n]

    return np.asarray(y_as_uint).view(dtype=np.float16)
```

The `view` function doesn't make a copy so is pretty cheap to use.

### 3) Do maths with manual conversions

If you want to do any calculations you'll need to use numpy's conversion functions to change your "half-float" data to full floats and back. If you forget to do this the answers you get will be meaningless. Start by including them from `numpy/halffloat.h`:

```
cdef extern from "numpy/halffloat.h":
    ctypedef uint16_t npy_half

    # conversion functions
    float npy_half_to_float(npy_half h);
    npy_half npy_float_to_half(float f);

def do_some_maths(x):
    assert x.dtype == np.float16
    cdef uint16_t[:] x_as_uint = x.view(np.uint16)

    cdef uint16_t[:] y_as_uint = np.empty(x.shape,dtype=np.uint16)

    for n in range(x_as_uint.shape[0]):
        y_as_uint[n] = npy_float_to_half(2*npy_half_to_float(x_as_uint[n]))

    return np.asarray(y_as_uint).view(dtype=np.float16)
```

This code requires you to [link against the numpy core math library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.coremath.html#linking-against-the-core-math-library-in-an-extension):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import get_info
info = get_info('npymath')

ext_modules = [Extension("module_name", ["module_name.pyx"],**info)]

setup(
  ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)
)
```

Comment: wouldn't this be at the <= speed compared to 32bit floats? It would only help with memory constraints ?

Comment: @DanErez Yes - I'd think there would be a speed penalty and that the main value would be less memory.