# how to add support for float16 type in array class

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, cython

Why does the C/Python array class does not support float16 ?

/ I can see that other projects like numba also dont have support float16/

Is there way to add support ? if yes is it easy ?

the reason i'm asking is because if an array is too big float32 takes twice the space.
Having an option seem reasonable ! if not available there have to be some reason

---

It seems the intel! CPUs, does not support float16 ops naively , but support conversion ..

```
lscpu | grep Flags | grep f16c
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F16C

Comment: what are you actually asking for? yes there are certainly ways to do whatever you are asking for but you code does not provide context or explain what underlying problem you are trying to solve (ie why does it matter to you if its float32 vs float16)

Comment: What are "prjs"?

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm assuming "projects" but questions should be clear

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421443/using-half-precision-numpy-floats-in-cython? The question isn't clear enough to know

Comment: @DavidW that kind of answers my question, thanks. should i delete this question .. ?

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean its not supported etc?

```
a_float_16 = numpy.zeros(10, dtype=numpy.float16)
```

Comment: But that's NumPy.

Comment: I believe they are referring to [the standard library `array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), although they did refer to `numba`...

Comment: or if theres an easy implementations `import numpy`....